# Почему округляет число сразу после ввода с клавиатуры?

Tags: c++, c, переменные

Нужно присвоить переменной Х число действительного типа к примеру 1.1. Сразу же после ввода с клавиатуры идёт округление и следовательно неправильный ответ в выражении и else if не срабатывает В чём ошибка?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

float x, w, b = -0.3, c = 4, a = 2.8;

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    printf("Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу...");
    getch();
    printf("\nВведите переменную x ->");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    if (x < 1.2) {
        w = a * pow(x, 2) + b*x + c;
    }
    else if (x == 1.2) {
        w = a / x + sqrt(pow(x, 2) + 1);
    }
    else {
        w = (a + b*x) / sqrt(pow(x, 2) + 1);
    }
    printf("\aa=%2.1f b=%2.1f c=%1.0f x=%2.1f w=%3.1f", a, b, c, x, w);
    getch();
    printf("\nДля завершения нажмите любую клавишу...");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Для некоторых чисел формат представления их с плавающей запятой в компьютере не позволяет хранить их точные значения.

Answer (score 4):

Для сравнения вещественных чисел на равенство нужно использовать примерно следующее:

```
if( fabs(a-b) < 0.000001 ) printf("Числа равны");
else printf("Числа не равны");
```

Распечатайте `х` сразу после `scanf("%f", &x);`

Answer (score 4):

Представление числа с плавающей точкой в памяти - приближенное, в виде суммы степеней двойки. Поэтому, как в десятичной записи точно не запишешь, скажем, 1/3 - нужно бесконечное количество цифр - так происходит и с числами в двоичной системе счисления. Поэтому происходит обрезка чисел до какой-то точности, и сравнивать числа на простое равенство в общем случае невозможно.

Ваш код еще сработал бы, как ни смешно - потому что вы вводите, скажем, 1.2 и сравниваете с 1.2 - т.е. их представления *одинаковы*, но дело в том, что вы зачем-то используете `float`, в то время как литерал `1.1` компилятор принимает как `double`, и представления одного и того же числа оказываются различными.

Так что сравнивать нужно исходя из `|a-b| < ε`, ну а каким выбрать ε - зависит от задачи и значений `a` и `b`.

Comment: Добавлю: в большинстве случаев в качестве `ε` можно взять `max(a, b) * numeric_limits<type_of_a>::epsilon()`.

Comment: @Arhad это ничем не лучше сравнения через `==`. `epsilon()` дает всего лишь единицу младшего разряда мантиссы, реально же надо откидывать несколько последних знаков.

Answer (score 0):

Так как вы локаль поменяли на русский (`setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");`), будьте внимательны, что вещественные числа в русской локали записываются через запятую.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

float x, w, b = -0.3, c = 4, a = 2.8;

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
// после этой команды, числа с плавающей запятой надо вводить через запятую!
    printf("Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу...");
    getch();
    printf("\nВведите переменную x ->");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    if (x < 1.2) {
        w = a * pow(x, 2) + b*x + c;
    }
    else if (x == 1.2) {
        w = a / x + sqrt(pow(x, 2) + 1);
    }
    else {
        w = (a + b*x) / sqrt(pow(x, 2) + 1);
    }
    printf("\aa=%2.1f b=%2.1f c=%1.0f x=%2.1f w=%3.1f", a, b, c, x, w);
    getch();
    printf("\nДля завершения нажмите любую клавишу...");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу...
Введите переменную x ->1,9
a=2,8 b=-0,3 c=4 x=1,9 w=1,0

Comment: хотел это как комментарий оставить, но репутации не хватает)